# CDI with Jetty is not working (not injecting beans)

Tags: java, jetty, cdi

I'm facing some issues with Jetty.

Basicaly, I'm trying to use CDI on Jetty using (in this case @Singleton from javax.inject), and @Inject on constructor, but it always get error (using mvn jetty:run)

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.test.controller.EngineController.()

Even if I use @Inject as field injection, TemplateManager always come null.

Example:

```java
@Singleton
public class EngineController extends HttpServlet {


    private TemplateManager templateManager;

    @Inject
    BeanManager beanManager;

    @Inject
    public EngineController (TemplateManager templateManager){
        this.templateManager = templateManager;
    }
}
```

```java
@Singleton
public class TemplateManager {

}
```

This is my beans file (located in webapp\WEB-INF:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
       version="1.2" bean-discovery-mode="all">
</beans>
```

And my web.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         metadata-complete="true" version="3.0" >
    <display-name>TEST</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Engine Template Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.test.controller.EngineController</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Engine Template Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Could someone provide me some help?

Comment: What CDI implementation have you added to your webapp?

Comment: Hi,
I just have the dependency on maven   <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: That's not enough, that's just an API with no implementation behind it.  Consider using an implementation (like weld), and configuring it properly for your environment.

Comment: Do you have some example that could provide me?